# My mongodb return the array empty []

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, database

I'm studying a build full stack JavaScript apps with the MEAN stack, using Node.js, AngularJS, Express and MongoDB.

I'm in the third section where I have to retrieve all the hotels in my database.

When in the browser I type http: // localhost: 3000 / api / hotels /, my database returns an empty array, but the hotel.data.json file is full.

I also tried a copied section5's teacher's final work, but I have the same result, my database is empty [].
This is the code of the hotels.controllers file:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Hotel = mongoose.model('Hotel');


module.exports.hotelsGetAll = function(req, res) {


  console.log('GET the hotels');
  console.log(req.query);

  var offset = 0;
  var count = 5;

  if (req.query && req.query.offset) {
    offset = parseInt(req.query.offset, 10);
  }

  if (req.query && req.query.count) {
    count = parseInt(req.query.count, 10);
  }

  Hotel
    .find()
    .skip(offset)
    .limit(count)
    .exec(function(err, hotels) {
      console.log("Found hotels", hotels.length);
      res
        .json(hotels);
    });

};

module.exports.hotelsGetOne = function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.hotelId;
  console.log('GET hotelId', id);

  Hotel
    .findById(id)
    .exec(function(err, doc) {
      res
        .status(200)
        .json(doc);
    });

};

module.exports.hotelsAddOne = function(req, res) {
  console.log("POST new hotel");
  var db = dbconn.get();
  var collection = db.collection('hotels');
  var newHotel;

  if (req.body && req.body.name && req.body.stars) {
    newHotel = req.body;
    newHotel.stars = parseInt(req.body.stars, 10);
    collection.insertOne(newHotel, function(err, response) {
      console.log("Hotel added", response);
      console.log("Hotel added", response.ops);
      res
        .status(201)
        .json(response.ops);
    });
    // console.log(newHotel);
    // res
    //   .status(200)
    //   .json(newHotel);
  } else {
    console.log("Data missing from body");
    res
      .status(400)
      .json({
        message: "Required data missing from body"
      });
  }

};
```

Comment: Where are you trying to pull data from? From DB or from json file?

Comment: Post your routes as well,  whats your console.log("Found hotels", hotels.length) shows

Comment: Are you getting your data from Mongo or from `hotel.data.json`? It's unclear

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.

This is the file of routes:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var ctrlHotels = require('../controllers/hotels.controllers.js');

// Hotel routes
router
  .route('/hotels')
  .get(ctrlHotels.hotelsGetAll);

router
  .route('/hotels/:hotelId')
  .get(ctrlHotels.hotelsGetOne);

router
  .route('/hotels/new')
  .post(ctrlHotels.hotelsAddOne);

module.exports = router;
```

My console.log() tell:

```js
GET /api/hotels
Requested by: undefined
GET the hotels
{}
(node:2780) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library ins
null
[]
Found hotels 0
```

I have a hothel-data.json file with all the hotels, the professor in the video at the command prompt when he connects to the db type mongod, but he gave me an error, so when I plug in the db type: mongod --dbpath = data.

I have a main folder, inside I have an API folder with 3 folders inside.

1 CONTROLLERS folder, with hotels-controllers.js, 2 DATA folder with db.js, dbconnection.js, hotel-data.json, hotels.model.js, and 3 ROUTES folder with index.js.

Answer (score 0):

I solved importing the hotel-data.json file, now it's ok, when typing ocalhost: 3000 / api / hotels I see all the hotels.

Thanks anyway.

Aurora